# Livewire doesn't trigger events when files are uploaded using $wire.$upload(...args)

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, alpine.js

I am uploading a file using the `$wire.$upload(...args)` but it does not trigger Livewire default upload events. it works when trying to upload it via `$wire:model`

This is what the `$upload` method looks like at `vendor/livewire/livewire/dist/livewire.js`:

```js
// A JS API to upload a file directly to component
// rather than through `wire:model`...

$upload(
    name, // The property name
    file, // The File JavaScript object
    finish = () => {
        ...
    }, // Runs when the upload is finished...
    error = () => {
        ...
    }, // Runs if an error is triggered mid-upload...
    progress = (event) => { // Runs as the upload progresses...
        event.detail.progress // An integer from 1-100...
    },
)
```

I'm listening to the event using AlpineJS.

```html
<div x-on:livewire-upload-start="console.log('upload started')"></div>
```

Comment: Please post any useful information to be able to formulate an answer: what version of Livewire are you using? You must also attach the part of your code where you use *$wire.$upload*

Answer (score 0):

Using *.window* modifier should get you the result you're looking for:

```html
<div x-on:livewire-upload-start.window="console.log('upload started')"></div>
```

Comment: It's not working either.

Comment: Then I guess the problem lies in the part of code that uses *$wire.$upload*: see my comment on the main question